# MODX SimpleSearch not highlighting results

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I want to use `&highlightResults` as shown in the RTFM to add a class to the keywords that appear in the results. However, this doesnt seem to work.

My snippet call looks like:

```
      [[!SimpleSearch?
            &ids=`21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,44,22`
            &idType=`parents`
            &tpl=`SearchResultTpl2016`
            &containerTpl=`SimpleSearchContainerTpl`
            &highlightResults=`1`
            &includeTVs=`1`
            &processTVs=`1`
            &showExtract=`1`
        ]]
```

I tried adding:

```
&highlightClass=`sisea-highlight`
&highlightTag=`span`
```

as well but it made no difference.

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you created a class definition in your css?

Comment: @SeanKimball no I haven't. The keywords arnt even being  wrapped by the span though

Comment: What versions of MODX and SimpleSearch are you using?

If you edit the `SimpleSearch` snippet then select Properties and change the highlightResults setting to Yes does this work?

Comment: If you remove `&highlightResults` altogether,  are the results wrapped in a span with the `class="sisea-highlight"`?